# LDAP is failing 'make test' with Segmentation fault

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am attempting to install LDAP on a virtual host. Following the quickstart guide I am building openldap on CentOS release 5.6 (Final). During configuration it complained about my BerkleyDB. So I built Berkeley DB 4.8.3 and ran

```
env CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib ./configure
```

Successfully working through the makes I am failing at `make test`

```
>>>>> Starting test060-mt-hot for bdb...
running defines.sh
Running slapadd to build slapd database...
Running slapindex to index slapd database...
Starting slapd on TCP/IP port 9011...
      /var/www/vhosts/poooblic.com/ldap/openldap-2.4.32/tests/../servers/slapd/slapd -s0 -f /var/www/vhosts/poooblic.com/ldap/openldap-2.4.32/tests/testrun/slapd.1.conf -h ldap://localhost:9011/ -
Testing basic monitor search...
Monitor searches
Testing basic mt-hot search: 1 threads (1 x 50000) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e cn=Monitor -m 1 -L 1 -l 50000
Testing basic mt-hot search: 5 threads (1 x 10000) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e cn=Monitor -m 5 -L 1 -l 10000
Testing basic mt-hot search: 100 threads (5 x 100) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e cn=Monitor -m 100 -L 5 -l 100 
Random searches
Testing random mt-hot search: 1 threads (1 x 50000) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e dc=example,dc=com -f (objectclass=*) -m 1 -L 1 -l 50000
Testing random mt-hot search: 5 threads (1 x 10000) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e dc=example,dc=com -f (objectclass=*) -m 5 -L 1 -l 10000
Testing random mt-hot search: 100 threads (5 x 100) loops...
./progs/slapd-mtread -H ldap://localhost:9011/ -D cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -w secret -e dc=example,dc=com -f (objectclass=*) -m 100 -L 5 -l 100 
./scripts/test060-mt-hot: line 190: 15747 Segmentation fault      $SLAPDMTREAD -H $URI1 -D "$MANAGERDN" -w $PASSWD -e "$BASEDN" -f "(objectclass=*)" -m $THR -L $OUTER -l $INNER >> $MTREADOUT 2>&1
slapd-mtread failed (139)!
>>>>> test060-mt-hot failed for bdb 
(exit 139)
make[2]: *** [bdb-yes] Error 139 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/www/vhosts/poooblic.com/ldap/openldap-2.4.32/tests'
make[1]: *** [test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/www/vhosts/poooblic.com/ldap/openldap-2.4.32/tests'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

I am not a sys admin and don't fully conceptualize the build process. What docs can I read to help me understand why it is failing and what can I do to work though it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below - feedback me incase of any issue.

cd db-4.7.25.NC

```
cd build_unix/
   ../dist/configure
    make
   make install
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/include"
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib"
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/db-4.7.25.NC/build_unix/.libs       ( change this path as per your)


  ./configure

   make depend
  make
  make test
```

Regards
Naveen

Comment: Thanks but the only new thing here is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I've gone into the BerkleyDB install directory and exported the variables as you have. However this doesn't change the make test failure and Segmentation Fault.